# Can't get a Cognitive Services Labs API key for Microsoft Academic

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

In order to access Microsoft Academics API (https://academic.microsoft.com/), I must request a key from Microsoft Cognitive Labs (https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions). In order to do so, I created a Hotmail account to be able to sign up, but I don't get the keys.

I already tried with my LinkedIn and GitHub accounts, but still can't get the key from Microsoft Cognitive Labs. [This screenshot shows how the Keys tab that should contain the keys is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQi01.png)

Comment: Maybe you should try to use a Microsoft account ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After you've signed in you need to "subscribe" to the service to get the access keys.

To subscribe to Project Academic Knowledge (the labs name for the Microsoft Academic API), go to https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-academic-knowledge and click the "subscribe" button.

Once you've done that you should be able to see the keys on the "keys" tab.